# ShowWindow() sets the width to the full screen width

Tags: delphi, showwindow

I have a child form that's `ManualDock`'d onto a panel from a larger form.

The problem is that when calling `ChildForm.Show()`, the width of `ChildForm` is set to `1920` by the `ShowWindow()` function from `user32.dll`. How do I prevent this behavior? Even if this is the documented default Windows behavior, how come Delphi doesn't resize the form to the specifications of the properties?

This behavior occurs *before* docking. When docking the form seems to take the width of the parent it's docked on (here a simple panel) but this means that I cannot rely on the the width of the form being correct at all times.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

To limit the size of the dockable form, use its `Constraints` property:

- `Constraints.MaxHeight`
- `Constraints.MaxWidth`
- `Constraints.MinHeight`
- `Constraints.MinWidth`

With those set, you can rely on the size of the form to be as you specify.